# What's with the format of Request.getRequestId()?

Tags: apex

I've been writing records with some Quiddities and some Request Ids for a logging application that I'm writing and I've noticed that the format of the request ids is widly different for some quiddities.

I'm not doing anything special to get these. Simply:

```
Request currentRequest = Request.getCurrent();
String currentRequestId = currentRequest.getRequestId();
String currentRequestQuiddityName = currentRequest.getQuiddity().name();
```

Is this expected? Is there a reason that they're so different? Here are some example results:

| Request Id | Quiddity |
| --- | --- |
| 4ttP65lJ4hwhTAX2-q7Cd- | ANONYMOUS |
| 4ts8aja69MqqffX2-qCWD- | QUEUEABLE |
| TID:17882539000050a458 | SYNCHRONOUS |

Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly what we see in the `PacakgeUsageLog` records for our app exchange packages. My guess is these are logged from significantly different parts of the platform and each has its own concept of request ID. The ones starting 4t seem to relate to Apex/VF/REST API, generally.

Comment: Salesforce is a collection of many various off-the-shelf hardware and software solutions, along with a lot of custom code developed over decades. As such, we'd expect to see different types of identifiers based on internal subsystem that's doing the logging. Publicly speaking, all one could really say is that each identifier uniquely identifies the transaction in one of several different logging systems Salesforce uses.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox and phil-w. I invite either of you to post your comments (or a variation of them) as an answer. I thought it was what you guys said, but it's good to have confirmation from a wider group